# What's the closest predecessor to this statement by C.S Peirce?

Tags: epistemology, perception

Peirce wrote the following:

> if one exerts certain kinds of volition, one will undergo inreturn
> certain  compulsory  perceptions   (CP  5.9)

I suppose it resembles Compte's "theory guides what we observe" but is there any statement that is closer in meaning?
What's the closest predecessor to that statement by C.S Peirce?

Comment: I think to understand this sentence one needs to see the subsequent ones:"*Now this sort of consideration, namely, that certain lines of conduct will entail certain kinds of inevitable experiences is what is called a "practical consideration". Hence is justified the maxim...*", and the maxim is the well-known pragmatic maxim. In particular, it has little to do with "theory guides what we observe", and it is hard to discern what you are looking for. The origin of the pragmatic maxim?

Comment: @Conifold So this sentence doesn't stand alone? Because as I quote it above it may have another more general interpretation. Namely when one decides on a certain course of action one is bound to have certain (types of) compulsory perceptions/ideas.

Comment: That's not what he means, rather the opposite. "Facts are hard things", the Secondness, actions get reactions that we have no control over, his "scholastic" realism, etc. One is bound to have compulsory perceptions because there is reality, and it flows into the meaning of concepts according to the pragmatic maxim.

Comment: @Conifold I trust you.I don't know Peirce as well as you do. So in "scholastic" realism they say something similar to that?

Comment: Scholastic realism is Peirce's own tag, it refers to the doctrine of Duns Scotus concerning reality of universals. However, Peirce's "pragmatic" interpretation of this reality is specific to him. He does not imagine them to be some sort of immaterial "things", but rather manifesting through those compulsory perceptions as regularities in them.